# Change Text On Hover With Special Cursor

Tags: javascript, css, text, hover

Please guide me on how to change text on hover, similar to the monopo website. I do not require the background. Only a simple circle effect (like a coloured background) and the text changing would do. Moreover, if possible i want the effect to be active only in a div called "about". [image] link to the website :
[https://monopo.london/](https://monopo.london)

Comment: Please post your attempt(s) here and indicate where it's not working.

Comment: Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see how they do it?

Comment: Yes, I did check out the website's source code inorder to replicate it. However, the code seems too overwhelming and complicated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you started.

The text in the 'lens' is in an element on top of the primary text. It is clipped into a circle at the mouse position on every mouse move. It's background is white so it looks as though it's overwriting the text beneath.

```html
<style>
  .about {
    position: relative;
    --x: -0;
    --y: -0;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
  
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    clip-path: circle(1em at var(--x) var(--y));
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<div class="about">
  <div class="underneath">This is some text <br>and some more</div>
  <div class="overlay">Different characters<br>and again more</div>
</div>
<script>
  const about = document.querySelector('.about');
  about.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    const x = event.clientX;
    const y = event.clientY;
    about.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
    about.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
  });
</script>
```

Edit: more context has now been given and the about element (class now renamed to aboutt)is inside other elements.

We need to get the position relative to .aboutt

```js
const about = document.querySelector('.aboutt');
about.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  let rect = about.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = event.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top; //y position within the element.
  about.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  about.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
});
```

```html
<style>
  .aboutt {
    position: relative;
    --x: -0;
    --y: -0;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
  
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    clip-path: circle(1em at var(--x) var(--y));
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<div class="aboutt">
  <div class="underneath">This is some text <br>and some more</div>
  <div class="overlay">Different characters<br>and again more</div>
</div>
```

Also note that in the actual site the background is an image which is mainly black so the white background will need to become background: black.

And the method will not be perfect against an image rather  than a plain color.

Comment: @A Haworth , so sorry to ask again but when I am trying to put the code into an existing file, the javascript of this effect is not working. Javascript code for other effects is working. However, when I put the code in a new web-page it is perfectly working. Any particular reason why? Please help.

Comment: I'd need a lot more info before being able to help on this one! Try some debugging - e.g. console.log when you enter the event handler. Is it doing anything? It may be that some other code has taken those events and not allowed them to propagate, for  example (just guessing here but it's somewhere to start).

Comment: I tried that, but nothing is happening in the console.  Here is a glimpse of what's happening : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TJ-xvFgnTteQmuyYU_6ccjUqBd5H9yOY/view?usp=sharing

Above the text is a div, with a background, texts and a navbar.

Comment: Well, something is happening, the circle disappears. Is console.log in that event handler not being run? Where have you put it?

Comment: I added it like this : console.log(about.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
<rest of the code> ). I'm so sorry if I'm making a blunder. I'm not well versed in javascript.

Comment: And sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I just found out that when I bring my cursor from down of the page to up, then only the bottom row is changing.   It works only when I bring my cursor from bottom to up, not from top, right or left. I think when I bring my mouse pointer to a certain position, then the effect is coming. No effect on the top row.

Comment: console.log should go inside the function just as a way to ensure that the mousemove is being seen. Put something like console.log(‘move seen’j; immediately after the {.

Comment: It's working.  But the console is saying that  "    about.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { " is undefined.

Comment: Yes it will. It's a bit weird console.logging an addEventListener - what I would normally do to ensure that a function is being called is to put a console.log inside the function. It makes no sense to console.log an addEventListener which has no special value that you are interested in. What we are interested in is whether that function is getting called on  mouse moves (or whether something else has taken that event handling over). So please put a console log inside the function.

Comment: Okay, I did it. I put in the console.log in the function, the the console is printing : mouse seen.

Comment: Is it printing that quite often?

Comment: Yes, every time I move the mouse.

Comment: So now console log the x and y values because the only thing I can think of is that I’m picking up the wrong values.

Comment: I put the following code :
console.log(--x); 
  console.log(--y); 
It is giving me error whenever I move my mouse pointer over the text : Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
"The move seen" is getting printed each time.

Comment: I suggested you console log x and y. You seem to be trying to console.log the CSS variable --x and --y. I wonder whether you maybe need to learn a little more about CSS and JS before proceeding with this code?

Comment: Okay then. I hadn't coded for ages and hence I lost touch. Let me learn more about javascript.  But thank you so much for taking out your time to help me :)) Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Hello . I know I have troubled you enough over the past 2 days. But curiosity got the best out of me and I experimented this effect on a template, and it's giving similar effects to the issue I'm facing. Here's the link for reference : https://textclipglitch.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-08-17.html
Moreover, i renamed the div .about to .aboutt

Comment: I have added another snippet which works on your site (if you also change the background from white to black).

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I cannot express my gratitude in words :D.. I'm so elated that it's working and all thanks to you :). Thank you for supporting me and assisting me throughout these two days.

Comment: It was good to have an interesting question for once!